# WebClient Timeout not respected

Tags: c#, console-application, webclient

I have created a new `WebClient` class that has a longer `Request.Timeout` property by inheriting the native `WebClient` class and overriding the `GetWebRequest` method:

```
public class LongerTimeoutWebClient : WebClient
{
    public LongerTimeoutWebClient()
    {
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest r = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        r.Timeout = 30 * 1000; //30 second timeout
        return r;
    }
}
```

I use this new `WebClient` class to call a number of web pages in Parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(links, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, link =>
        {
            byte[] requestBytes;

            var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            using (var client = new LongerTimeoutWebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

                    stopwatch.Start();
                    requestBytes = client.DownloadData(link);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not get: " + link + ". Timeout after: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "s");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    return;
                }
            }
//More code here
}
```

However, I am intermittently getting a `408 Request Timeout` error. The stopwatch value when Timeout error occurs is around 20s.

I have also checked the `Timeout` property of the `Request` object used by the `GetWebResponse` method of the new `WebClient` class and it is set to 30000 (ms).

I have set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1 and I still get the errors, so that probably means the parallelization is not the cause of the problem.

Why is my `Request` getting timed out at 20s instead of 30s?

Comment: What is the request timeout set on the webserver serving this client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kind of timeouts. Client timeout and server timeout. Probably in this case what you are encountering is server timeout. Check it once.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. The server is probably timing out the requests once in a while due to the number of requests they're receiving.